# display number with minimum width of 0

Tags: python, string

I have searched but only found items showing leading zeros, not this edge case:
I need to have the equivalent of Excel's # in a number format, (which results in 0 displaying a result of zero length, or empty string)

if I do

```
i = 0
'{}{:02}'.format('prefix', i)
```

I get

```
prefix00
```

(as expected from PEP 3101), however specifying a width of 0 does not produce what I need. which is something like

```
i = 0
'{}{:0}'.format('prefix', i)
```

to produce

```
prefix
```

rather than

```
prefix0
```

as I currently get.  Is this inconsistent in the string format function?  Is there a way to create this in the format specifier (rather than a explicit test for zero?)

Comment: Why do you need this? Why even specify the format if you just want it to not be there?

Comment: @ruohola presumably it's not really a hard-coded `0` that's being formatted..

Comment: @Blorgbeard - thanks for a helpful comment, OP amended to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
n=0
"{}{}".format("prefix",n or "")
```

or

```
f"prefix{n or ''}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ternary conditional format pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) for the win:

```
for k in range(5):
    print( ('{}' if k == 0 else '{}{:02}').format('prefix', k))
```

Output:

```
prefix
prefix01
prefix02
prefix03
prefix04
```

The pattern changes based on `k`'s value - if you have too many params inside format it works,too few would throw an IndexError.

---

You could also go for

```
for k in range(5):
    print( 'prefix' if k == 0 else f'prefix{k:02}' )
```

using python 3.6 string literal interpolation.

Comment: This works, but "Is there a way to create this in the format specifier (rather than a explicit test for zero?)"

Comment: @Blorg not that I can think of - this is about the simples way to make it happen - you could also construct something with a formatfunction that inspects k or fiddle around with `strip('0')` afterwards if only 1 digit is at the end and it is 0 etc. but I think its more clunky